# When Im running the android it starts emulator not physical device when react-native run-android

Tags: react-native, adb, daemon, start-stop-daemon

I was running the application over Physical device after only I start to run application without physical device Emulator opened once and after that My MacOS machine never recognize my physical device as a adb device

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do. Can you provide us with more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Try running "adb devices" in terminal on root folder and see if your device is listed there. Once the device starts getting battery charged after connection, means the connection is made and should install the app on device.
Happens to me sometimes , but I fix by re-connecting the cable from the device and system multiple times.
And run react-native android only after this connection is made